# struts String array order

Tags: struts-1

I am  using a string array in a jsp file. Does strut gurantee that the order in which i am enetring the data will be same when i am retriving the data?

String name[];

in jsp there are multiple nos of propert 'name'. When i am retriving the value in action class, does the order remian same?
Please help me. Though i have not got any error, still i have doubt on this.
Thanks

Comment: I don't think Struts has anything to do with it, it will get the parameter order from the Servlet API, which gets it from HTTP, so the following PHP question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565938/will-data-order-in-post-form-be-the-same-to-it-in-web-form

Comment: and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382931/are-the-order-of-checkboxes-in-the-form-and-the-post-array-the-same

Answer (score 1):

Struts will ensure the order *submitted by the browser* is maintained once the form is submitted to the server.  The order that those array values are submitted by the browser is up to the browser, not struts, but the good news is the standard indicates the array values should be submitted in the same order they appear in the page, and every browser I've ever used does this correctly.